# NIntegrate With Singularity: Experiment With Various Parameters

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning

I want to numerically evaluate the integral
$$I = \int_{\mathbb R^2} dxdy f^*(x) f(y) K(x-y)dxdy,$$
where
$$f(x) = \sqrt{\frac 2 \pi} e^{ikx} e^{-x^2}, \quad k\in\mathbb R$$
is an exponentially decaying function, and
$$K(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} (-i(x+ia))^{-1/3}, \quad a>0,$$
is a kernel with "smeared-out" power-law singularity $K(x) \sim (x+ia)^{-1/3}$.

One can prove that $I$ is well-defined, even for $a=0$, and we always have $I>0$ for all $k$ and $a$. Furthermore, I know the analytic result for $I$ when $a=0$. It is:

```
(Sqrt[3] Gamma[2/
  3] (Gamma[1/6] Hypergeometric1F1[1/3, 1/2, -(k^2/4)] + 
   k Gamma[2/3] Hypergeometric1F1[5/6, 3/2, -(k^2/4)]))/(4 2^(
 1/6) \[Pi]^2)
```

I tried to numerically integrate $I$. Since $I$ is strongly localized near origin, I restricted the integral to the box $[-r,r] \times [-r,r]$, where $r>0$. I tried both `GlobalAdaptive` and `LocalAdaptive` method.

```
integrand = (1/Pi^2)  E^(-I k (x - y) - (x^2 + y^2))/((-I (I a + x - y))^(1/3)) 
rule = {a -> 1/10000, k -> 6};
r = 5;
NIntegrate[
  integrand /. rule, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.7442, 0.0458505 - 0.00440936 I} *)
```

Taking experiment with various parameters, I obtained:

[image]

`Re(res)` and `Im(res)` are the numerical result, `time` is the computational time, and `exact` is the analytic result at $a=0, r=\infty$ for all cases.
The result is disastrous! (The red cells are unhappy. Either result is wrong, or too much time is needed.) I have the following observations:

1. Although the integral should converge for $a=0$, smaller $a$ tends to make the result worse, either by time (`LocalAdaptive`) or accuracy (`lobalAdaptive`).
2. Although the integral exponentially decays, changing $r=5$ to 10 gives an inaccurate result, even for `LocalAdaptive`.

Is there any strategy for obtaining more accurate result, or obtaining faster result? Or, is there any qualitative explanation why changing either one of $a,r$ or method gives the tremendous difference?

Comment: Try `NIntegrate[Im[integrand /. rule] + 1, {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}] - 4^r^2`.

Comment: Also look at the result of `Plot3D[Re[integrand /. rule], {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, 
 PlotRange -> All]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing the singularity at `x==y` it is clever to change the coordinates

```
sol = Solve[{u == x + y, v == x - y}, {x, y}][[1]]
det = D[{x, y} /. sol, {{v,u}}] // Det (* 1/2*)
x^2+y^2/.sol//Expand (*1/2(u^2+v^2) *)

integranduv=integrand /. sol // Simplify
(*E^(-(u^2/2) - 1/2 v (2 I k + v))/(\[Pi]^2 (a -I v)^(1/3))*)
```

Integrand is a product of `function[u]*function[v] !

solution:

```
int[a_, k_] :=Integrate[det Exp[-u^2/2], {u, -#, #}] NIntegrate[E^(-(1/2) v (2 I k + v))/(\[Pi]^2 (a - Iv)^(1/3)), {v, -#, #},  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"] &

int[0, 6][5]//AbsoluteTiming (* last argument: integration range*)
(*{0.0340029, 0.0917014 - 6.08075*10^-18 I} *)
```

Further enlargement of the integration range ( `Exp[-5^2]==O[10^-11],Exp[-10^2]==O[10^-44]` ) requires adjustment of the accuracy-settings inside `NIntegrate`  !

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have a question on your last sentence. Why the small integrand is related to the adjustment of the accuracy settings?

Comment: Although your change-of-variable solution is very clever, it is sad that this is hard to generalize. Actually, the above is a toy example, and my real interest is to evaluate the integral
$$\int dx_1\cdots dx_n f(x_1,\ldots, x_n),$$
where $f$ has a singular behavior
$$f(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = \prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n} (x_i-x_j+ia)^{-1/3}.$$
In this situation, your idea is hard to apply. Are there any other ideas?

Comment: @eigenvalue For the case n=2 you could switch to polarcoordinates!

Comment: @eigenvalue Adjustment of accuracy is necessary, because Mathematica has to handle numbers which are very small.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very interestingly, setting the integral region as
`{x,-5,0,5}, {y,-5,0,x,5}`
and using the `LocalAdaptive` option makes the code much efficient. This works for large $r$.

Comment: Also, I wonder setting `AccuracyGoal` matters for larger $r$. I know that the integral is peaked near $(x,y) = (0,0)$, and far from there the integrand is very small. Although `AccuracyGoal` is not large enough so that this small integrand is treated as 0, why is it a problem? Anyway, the main contribution of the integral will come from $(x,y) = (0,0)$, and the default `AccuracyGoal` can capture this non-small integrand.